# Strange behavior of PlotMarkers with ListLinePlot[] and InterpolationOrder->0

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

I want to create a `ListLinePlot[]` with `InterpolationOrder->0`. However, when using plot markers like in

```
ListLinePlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

the plot markers become mixed up.

How can this be avoided?

Comment: This has been around a while.  Is it a confirmed bug or perhaps an "unexpected" feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get rid of the mixed up points you can specify `Mesh->Full`.

```
ListLinePlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Mesh -> Full, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image]

Here you can see the effect of the `Mesh` option when plotting interpolated data:

```
GraphicsGrid[
  Partition[
  ListLinePlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}},
  Mesh -> #, PlotLabel -> ToString[#], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0] & /@ {None, 10, All, Full}, 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is working! What exactly does the option  Mesh->Full ?

Comment: Literally from the documentation for `Mesh`: `Full` mesh divisions between regular data points.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but to show more clearly that there is a mix up. Plotting the lines separate and adding them in `Show` does not have the mix up.

```
d1 = {1, 2, 3, 5, 8};
d2 = {2, 3, 6, 9, 10};
d3 = {4, 5, 7, 10, 12};
plts = ListLinePlot[#, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotStyle -> First[#], 
    ImageSize -> 200] &;

Grid[{
  {plts /@ {d1, d2, d3}},
  {Show[plts /@ {d1, d2, d3}, PlotRange -> All]},
  {plts@{d1, d2, d3}}
  }, Spacings -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

using version 9.0.1 on windows